# Unity procedural mesh with different colours/texture per layer

Tags: unity, procedural-generation

I'm generating a procedural mesh, which is a 9x9 grid of cubes. I've written it so that none of the internal faces are rendered, until a cube above it has been removed, at which point the new faces are added. Think Minecraft voxels.

What I'd like to do is to have a texture over the entire outside of the cube, and then for each layer of the cube down towards its centre, have a different colour.

So the outside would have some arbitrary texture, and when a hole is punched in it, it shows a green cube beneath, and then a yellow cube beneath that, and so on down.

Or alternatively, use a single texture, with different coloured areas on it.  Then depending on the faces distance from the centre of the mesh, use a different section of the texture.   So update the UV mapping for the given face.

Is this something that is best achieved with a customer shader, or can anyone suggest another way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen on the faces that bridge two layers? For instance, if I drill a tunnel all the way through the cube, what should the walls of the tunnel look like? You will likely need a custom shader for this, unless you find that tinting the texture with vertex colours or sampling different parts of the texture with the vertex UVs is enough to capture the look you want. How have you tried generating the UVs for your faces at each layer so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything with the UVs at the moment, as I wasn't sure how best to approach it.  My current idea is to use a texture atlas, and set the UVs when the mesh is generated, based on the position of the faces.  However, you raise a good point, not sure about writing a custom shader, but can UV colours be displayed by the standard Unity shader?

Comment: Some Unity shaders use vertex colours, like the particle, sprite, and text shaders. Others don't.